# Is this that simple?

Tags: installation

I have a computer that has no operating system.  I am currently downloading ubuntu to a memory stick in a usb port, later, I will try to upload it onto my computer.  Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it isn't that simple, first of all you have to follow this instructions:

- For Windows ([here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows))
- For Linux ([here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu))
- For MacOSx ([here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx))

Then go to BIOS setup (When you turn on your computer hit `F2` until you enter in the BIOS setup) and set the USB stick as the first bootable device, then you will be able to install Ubuntu in your computer with that USB stick.

If you have any other questions, please let us know.

Note: Within the links there is detailed information to follow if you get stucked.

Comment: And it depends on your hardware, not all hardware is compatible with linux

Comment: Selecting it as a Boot Device before it boots is better, as if it is set as first bootable device, it will try and boot using USB sticks as default... Also, you can use `<kbd>F2</kbd>` in your answer instead of a code block of `F2` :-)